# How use WMI add route table with C#

Tags: c#, wmi, routetable

I want to use **Win32_IP4RouteTable** to add route table

code:

```
ManagementClass wmiclass = new ManagementClass("Win32_IP4RouteTable");
ManagementObject route = wmiclass.CreateInstance();
route["Destination"] = "145.63.20.102";
route["NextHop"] = "172.16.213.2";
route["Mask"] = "255.255.255.255";
route["Metric1"] = 20;
route.Put();//or route.Put(new PutOptions() { Type = 
PutType.UpdateOrCreate });
```

I get an Exception on *Put()* method:

```
`System.Management.Management:Invalid parameter`
```

How could I use Put method to create a new Item

Comment: I had to make a c++ library that performed some tasks like this. If I remember correctly, `Win32_IP4RouteTable` is used to read those settings, not to modify them. At that time, I'm pretty sure I used [CreateIpForwardEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365860(VS.85).aspx) for this. It's part of the [IPHelper Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366071(v=vs.85).aspx). I'm not sure about a c# implementation, though. Try this SO question: [Programmatically add route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29601017/programmatically-add-route)

Comment: Hi,I've solved this problem ,use IPHelper, Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Maybe, post your solution as an answer, it could be useful to someone else.

Comment: Thank you again ,I have post my soluntion

Answer (score 0):

like this,Thanks for @Jimi
`

```
    [DllImport("Iphlpapi.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public static extern int CreateIpForwardEntry(ref MIB_IPFORWARDROW pRoute);

   public static int createIpForwardEntry(UInt32 destIPAddress, UInt32 destMask, UInt32 nextHopIPAddress, UInt32 ifIndex, int metric)
    {
        MIB_IPFORWARDROW mifr = new MIB_IPFORWARDROW();
        mifr.dwForwardDest = destIPAddress;
        mifr.dwForwardMask = destMask;
        mifr.dwForwardNextHop = nextHopIPAddress;
        mifr.dwForwardIfIndex = ifIndex;
        mifr.dwForwardPolicy = Convert.ToUInt32(0);
        mifr.dwForwardType = Convert.ToUInt32(3);
        mifr.dwForwardProto = Convert.ToUInt32(3);
        mifr.dwForwardAge = Convert.ToUInt32(0);
        mifr.dwForwardNextHopAS = Convert.ToUInt32(0);
        mifr.dwForwardMetric1 = metric;
        mifr.dwForwardMetric2 = -1;
        mifr.dwForwardMetric3 = -1;
        mifr.dwForwardMetric4 = -1;
        mifr.dwForwardMetric5 = -1;
        return CreateIpForwardEntry(ref mifr);
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) library for this. It is a light ORM for WMI.

1) Define your class:

```
[WMIClass("Win32_IP4RouteTable")]
public class RouteTable
{
    public string Destination{ get; set; }
    public string NextHop{ get; set; }
    public string Mask{ get; set; }
    public string Metric1{ get; set; }
}
```

NOTE: It seems there are some properties that might be required so due to that you get 'Invalid Parameter'. If that is the case, then just add the needed clases to the `RouteTable` class.

2) Use the library:

```
WMIHelper helper = new WMIHelper("root\\CimV2");

RouteTable route = new RouteTable
{
    Destination = "145.63.20.102",
    NextHop = "172.16.213.2",
    Mask = "255.255.255.255",
    Metric1 = "20"
};

helper.AddInstance(route);
```

And that´s it.